# How to correctly scale SVG to cover 90% of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, svg, animated, velocity.js

I have an SVG image (a rectangle) inlined in my html code

```html
<svg id="theSVG" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" overflow="visible" ... >
  <polyline id="theElement">...</polyline>
</svg>
```

I am then trying to use jQUery and velocity.js to animate this to fill up all the screen but one edge (to about 90%/90% right/bottom). Which looks like this:

```js
...
$("theSVG").velocity({scale: 10}, {duration: 1000});
```

This solution has two problems though:

- how do I scale this to exactly fit 90% of the screen?
- If the scale is bigger than about 2-3 the SVG's edges get fuzzy. I read this happens if you don't directly target the SVG (but I am doing just that?!)

Is there any good solution to this?

I also tried to set the svg to 100%/100% and play around with the viewport and scale that up later... but I can't seem to be able to user percentages there..

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply tried using the `width` attribute or the `width` property of `style`?

```
<svg id="theSVG" width="90%" overflow="visible" ... >
    <polyline id="theElement">...</polyline>
</svg>
```

or

```
<svg id="theSVG" style="width:90%;" overflow="visible" ... >
    <polyline id="theElement">...</polyline>
</svg>
```

[Similar Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368410/how-to-set-svg-width-and-svg-height-by-percent).

Then again, CSS is probably the way to go as usual:

```
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#theSVG
{
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the width attrib deprecated  in HTML5? Or still allowed only for SVG?

Comment: width is [deprecated if used with](http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html) `<hr>`, `<pre>`, `<td>` or `<th>`. Note that I recommend CSS anyway.